# ! Package pdftex.def Error: File `first_sketch.pdf' not found

Tags: graphics

I am trying to compile image which I created by Inkscape but I am getting the following error

```
! Package pdftex.def Error: File `first_sketch.pdf' not found.
```

the PDF file `first_sketch` is in the image folder with the `first_sketch.pdf_tex` and it is in PDF format. What does this error mean?

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl}   % Article class 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%Vektor graphic packages%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{transparent}
\graphicspath{{image/}}


%%% Begin document
\begin{document}


  \begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
  \def\svgwidth{175pt}
  \input{image/first_sketch.pdf_tex}

    \caption{Test}
    \label{fig2}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [! Paragraph ended before \graphicspath was complete](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/226781/paragraph-ended-before-graphicspath-was-complete)

Comment: Why ask it again?

Comment: I thought it is better because the error in the title is not the same

Comment: Should I delete it?

Comment: Try to reduce your code to a simple one so we can read it clearly. Also, use the button `{}` to format the code.

Comment: Ok I will do it but I have a problem with {} if I click it just formats one line and I do not know how to format the entire block :(

Comment: just select the block first and after use the button :)

Comment: @ocean you can edit the question if there was a mistake in the title, don't ask the same question again, you should delete one of them if they are the same.

Comment: sorry I clicked the blockquote and then the {} but that was the result :( The error that I am getting now after deleting the other syntex lines of the file is "! Undefined control sequence."

Comment: @ocean: You're not using what was suggested: `\graphicspath{{image/}}`.

Comment: I added the braces but I am always getting this error "! Undefined control sequence."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\graphicspath` is used to set the paths where graphics may reside for use within your file/project. It has the following form:

```
\graphicspath{{<first/path>}{<second/path>}...{<last/path>}}
```

Note the fact that each elements within the set of paths have braces around it. This holds true for even a single path (`\graphicspath{{<a/single/path>}}`).

Regardless, you also need to

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

in order to use any form of graphics, *before* setting any `\graphicspath`.

Comment: After adding the \usepackage{graphics} it works but after compiling,  the letterings are distorted. How can I minimize the image so that the letterings above the arrows are minimized too?

Comment: maybe it will help if I find out how to change the length of the pdf file? as \svgwidth for width.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the error means exactly what it says:  LaTeX can't find the file that you're telling it to input.  It's impossible for us to tell you why it's doing that because you didn't give us a minimum working example to save and run.

For future reference, this is more like a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\begin{document}
\input{image/first_sketch.pdf_tex}
\end{document}
```

I get the expected result with no errors when running this code.  However, I got the same result running your code as posted above, when I removed the `\graphicspath` command.  Before I removed that, I got a different error from yours.  My thought, therefore, is that your problem is likely related to `\graphicspath`.  I'd suggest reading the documentation on it carefully; and if you can't resolve it, consider just getting rid of it.  Since you seem to be putting the directory name in your `\input` command anyway, this shouldn't be a problem.

If this doesn't solve your problem, construct a real MWE for people to test.  To do this, keep paring down your file, one line at a time if necessary, until you've got the smallest possible file which still produces the error.  Often this will show you what the problem is all by itself; if it doesn't, at least others can look at your work and not have to worry about a lot of code that's probably completely unrelated to the issue.

I hope this helps.