# Package pdftex.def Error: File `myscript-pics.pdf' not found: using draft setting

Tags: pstricks, templates, eps, dvips, auto-pst-pdf

I am writing my thesis, and for this, I have downloaded my institute's latex template to work with. I have been getting an error with the compilation since the first ever unedited run of the template itself. I am using MikTex with TexWorks on Windows 10.

The MWE for my problem (`myscript.tex`) is:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[pspdf={-dAutoRotatePages=/None},pdfcrop={ --hires}]{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage[]{pstricks}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\includegraphics{example-image-a.eps}
\end{center}

\begin{figure}[t]
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(5,2)
    \psgrid
\end{pspicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The console output in TexWorks that I get after running it is:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (MiKTeX 20.7)
entering extended mode
(myscript.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-07-17>
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\book.cls"
Document Class: book 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\bk10.clo"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/auto-pst-pdf\auto-pst-pdf.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/iftex\ifpdf.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/iftex\iftex.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/xkeyval\xkeyval.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/xkeyval\xkeyval.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/xkeyval\xkvutils.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/xkeyval\keyval.tex"))))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/ifplatform\ifplatform.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/tools\shellesc.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pdftexcmds\pdftexcmds.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/infwarerr\infwarerr.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/ltxcmds\ltxcmds.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/catchfile\catchfile.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/etexcmds\etexcmds.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/iftex\ifluatex.sty"))" "
"-------------------------------------------------"
"auto-pst-pdf: Auxiliary LaTeX compilation"
"-------------------------------------------------"
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (MiKTeX 20.7)
entering extended mode
This is dvips(k) 2020.1 Copyright 2020 Radical Eye Software (www.radicaleye.com)
' TeX output 2020.08.04:1253' -> myscript-autopp.ps
<C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/dvips/base/tex.pro>
<C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/dvips/config/alt-rule.pro>
<C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/dvips/pstricks/pstricks.pro>
<C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/dvips/pstricks/pst-algparser.pro>
<C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/dvips/pst-tools/pst-tools.pro>
<C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/dvips/pstricks/pst-dots.pro>
<C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/dvips/l3backend/l3backend-dvips.pro>
<C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmss17.pfb>
<C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/dvips/base/special.pro>. [1
<C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/latex/mwe/example-image-a.eps>] [2] 
Error: /undefinedfilename in (-dAutoRotatePages=/None)
Operand stack:

Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:969/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:78/200(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: No such file or directory
MiKTeX GPL Ghostscript 9.25: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
"-------------------------------------------------"
"auto-pst-pdf: End auxiliary LaTeX compilation"
"-------------------------------------------------"


Package auto-pst-pdf Warning: 
    Creation of myscript-autopp.pdf failed.
This warning occured on input line 124.


Package auto-pst-pdf Warning: 
    Could not create myscript-pics.pdf. Auxiliary files not deleted.
This warning occured on input line 124.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/pst-pdf\pst-pdf.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/iftex\ifxetex.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/iftex\ifvtex.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/luatex85\luatex85.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\graphicx.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\graphics.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\trig.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\graphics.cfg")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-def\pdftex.def")))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/pstricks\pstricks.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/xcolor\xcolor.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\color.cfg"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/xkeyval\pst-xkey.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pstricks\pstricks.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pstricks\pst-fp.tex"
`pst-fp' v0.05, 2010/01/17 (hv))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfutil-common.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfutil-common-lists.tex"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfkeys.code.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfkeysfiltered.code.tex"))
 ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgffor.code.tex"
Loading pgffor.code.tex
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmath.code.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathcalc.code.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathutil.code.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathparser.code.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.code.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.tex"
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.trigonometric.c
ode.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.random.code.tex
")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.comparison.code
.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.base.code.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.round.code.tex"
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.tex
")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.integerarithmet
ics.code.tex")))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfloat.code.tex")))
`PSTricks' v2.97  <2019/05/11> (tvz,hv)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pstricks\pstricks.con"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pstricks\pst-fp.tex"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/preview\preview.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-def\dvips.def")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/environ\environ.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/trimspaces\trimspaces.sty"))))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/mwe\mwe.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/lipsum\lipsum.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-pdfmode.def"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3packages/xparse\xparse.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3packages/xparse\xparse-generic.tex"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/lipsum\lipsum.ltd.tex"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/blindtext\blindtext.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/tools\xspace.sty"))) (myscript.aux)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/context/base/mkii\supp-pdf.mkii"
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
)
Preview: Fontsize 10pt
Preview: PDFoutput 1

LaTeX Warning: File `myscript-pics.pdf' not found on input line 10.


! Package pdftex.def Error: File `myscript-pics.pdf' not found: using draft set
ting.

See the pdftex.def package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.10 \includegraphics{example-image-a.eps}
                                          
?
```

I tried the solutions as suggested in the following SX answers:

1. [suparnob10's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/443865/213931) and [Werner's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/226817/213931): Adding `\graphicspath{{<first/path>}{<second/path>}...{<last/path>}}`
2. [Re-installation of MikTex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/416023/213931)
3. [Installing perl and ghostscript](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/473106/213931) : Do I need to do anything besides just installing them to make this solution marked as 'tried'? I have currently only installed them.
4. [Adding `dvipsnames` as an option while importing `pstricks`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/373575/213931) led me to another error: `! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package pstricks.`. This clash was probably with `trimspaces.sty` as that was the earlier line.
5. Loading `auto-pst-pdf` after `pstricks` as suggested by the [comment by Bernard on the original post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/326250/one-more-time-auto-pst-pdf-does-not-work)

I am running the script using pdflatex with `-shell-escape` enabled, as that is needed for `auto-psd-pdf`.

*PS: I have included the `\begin{figure}\begin{pspicture}..\end{figure}` in the MWE just to highlight that the `pstricks` package is needed in the template.*

---

## **Update**

On removing the `pspdf={-dAutoRotatePages=/None}` option while loading `auto-pst-pdf`, as suggested by @Ulrike Fischer a part of the error saying `Error: /undefinedfilename in (-dAutoRotatePages=/None)` has been replaced with:

```
Sorry, but pdfcrop did not succeed for the following reason:

  MiKTeX could not find the script engine 'perl.exe' which is required to execute 'pdfcrop'.

Remedy:

  Make sure 'perl.exe' is installed on your system.
The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:\Users\aashay\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\miktex\log\pdfcrop.log
```

However, I do have perl installed on my system: On inputting `perl -v` in cmd, i get:

```
This is perl 5, version 30, subversion 2 (v5.30.2) built for MSWin32-x64-multi-thread
```

The log file `pdfcrop.log` is as follows:

```
2020-08-04 15:38:50,326+0200 INFO  pdfcrop - this process (3308) started by 'cmd' with command line: pdfcrop --hires myscript-autopp.pdf myscript-pics.pdf
2020-08-04 15:38:50,340+0200 FATAL pdfcrop.core - The script engine could not be found.
2020-08-04 15:38:50,340+0200 FATAL pdfcrop.core - Data: scriptEngine="perl.exe", scriptName="pdfcrop"
2020-08-04 15:38:50,340+0200 FATAL pdfcrop.core - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Session\runperl.cpp:83
2020-08-04 15:38:50,341+0200 FATAL pdfcrop - The script engine could not be found.
2020-08-04 15:38:50,341+0200 FATAL pdfcrop - Info: scriptEngine="perl.exe", scriptName="pdfcrop"
2020-08-04 15:38:50,341+0200 FATAL pdfcrop - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Session\runperl.cpp
2020-08-04 15:38:50,341+0200 FATAL pdfcrop - Line: 83
```

Comment: what do you get if you call `where perl.exe` on the command line?

Comment: I get `C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe`, the installation directory of perl.

Comment: are you running miktex from some special setup which could change the path and hide perl?

Comment: I couldn't understand what you meant by a 'special setup'. But my miktex root directories are `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX` for Install purposes and `C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX` for config and data purposes. Additionally the links to MiKTeX executables have been installed in `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64`. While miktex installation, I followed the standard procedure by keeping all the settings as default. I hope this helps towards your question

Comment: I've updated the question to contain the log file `pdfcrop.log`

Comment: Did you tried: `pspdf={-dAutoRotatePages\#/None}` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On windows the equal sign in the pspdf option is a bit problematic. Try it like this:

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand\hashchar{}
\edef\hashchar{\c_hash_str}
\ExplSyntaxOff
%use \hashchar instead of =:
\usepackage[pspdf={-dAutoRotatePages\hashchar/None},pdfcrop={ --hires}]{auto-pst-pdf}
```

(or remove the pspdf option, perhaps you don't need it ...)

Comment: I tried removing the pspdf option and also tried replacing equal sign with \hashchar as defined by you. Nonetheless, the error persisted.

Comment: I can't really believe that you get the error `Error: /undefinedfilename in (-dAutoRotatePages=/None)` if you don't use the option.

Comment: Yes. Sorry, You are correct. This part of the error has now been replaced with another error saying that `MiKTeX could not find the script engine 'perl.exe' which is required to execute 'pdfcrop'.` However perl is installed on my system as I do get the version i perform `perl -v`. I'll updated the original post with this too.

Answer (score 0):

**The solution**, in my case was *threefold*:

1. As suggested by @Ulrike Fischer, i removed the `pspdf`/ edited it by replacing the equal sign. (For this point, I have accepted that answer for this question.)
2. (and 2.5.) [I read](https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/377) that some people were experiencing problems when the pdfcrop was was installed before perl was installed. Additionally, I had installed strawberry perl earlier. I uninstalled strawberry perl and installed active perl (Though I do not know why that should affect it. Hence I have am confused whether it was twofold/ threefold :P).
3. Then I manually reinstalled `pdfcrop` from MiKTeX console.

After doing this, the I was able to run the MWE (and by induction, my main thesis files too) successfully.

Answer (score 0):

For windows:

```
\usepackage[pspdf={-dAutoRotatePages\#/None},pdfcrop={ --hires}]{auto-pst-pdf}
```

Comment: It is a _complete_ and _valid_ line of code!